# PHP upgrade is giving my Wordpress Blog errors

Tags: php, wordpress

I just did an Apache upgrade and perhaps I also updated the PHP (but not 100% sure), my site: http://www.villagedrinks.co.uk/ is now getting these errors, I dont actualy even use WP on my site, any help really appreciated. My general coding abilty is reasonably limited . Thanks Greg
Following are the errors/Warnings:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/village/public_html/blog/wp-includes/cache.php on line 36

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/village/public_html/blog/wp-includes/query.php on line 21

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/village/public_html/blog/wp-includes/theme.php on line 507

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/village/public_html/blog/wp-includes/cache.php:36) in /home/village/public_html/includes/inc_functions.php on line 22
```

Comment: How old is your version of WP? (You must be using some part of it somewhere.)

Comment: May be you need set define('WP_DEBUG', false) in wp-config.php file

Comment: @KostiaShiian; This wont change the fact that the WP setup is outdated.

Comment: @Daniel. Yes, it is necessary to upgrade WP :). And answers about edit error_reporting in php.ini are not 100% correct. I would suggest to change wp-config.php becouse wp_debug_mode function do it (change error reporting level).

Answer (score 1):

Change your `error_reporting` PHP variable in your php.ini to `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED` as recommended for production servers.  Then restart your webserver.  This will suppress the deprecation notices and fix your `session_start()` problem.

Comment: @Daniel: I haven't run WP in ages so I'm unfamiliar, does every page use index.php?  If not, then that wouldn't work too well.

Comment: Yes, the index.php (AFAIK) is the proxy/catch-all point. Edit: yes accordingly to http://davidwalsh.name/wordpress-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

You definitely are using Wordpress: http://www.villagedrinks.co.uk/blog/

You're getting warnings because your Wordpress install is ancient:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 2.2.1" />
```

Upgrade Wordpress (the current version is 3.5) or just delete the `/blog/` folder completely.

Having an old version installed is insecure and will allow someone to get into your site through one of the [numerous unpatched bugs](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-2337/product_id-4096/version_id-45986/Wordpress-Wordpress-2.2.1.html).

Comment: Have removed the /blog/ folder which fixed the errors on the home page, but realised different issues now when a user logs in so for example using greg.healey@btinternet.com and password gjh999 you see the errorL Fatal error: Call to undefined function login_village() in /home/village/public_html/includes/inc_functions.php on line 129 other errors also when try and log out?